# Issue with cam access in Android streaming application

Tags: android, camera, streaming

I'm using [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) that works well on many devices, on others when I start the streaming I've a strange behaviour in the logcat and the streaming doesn't work: it is full of this tag: Camera  ( 6254): RRF

In the specific, this is what happens

```
D/MtkOmxVenc(  133): ENCODE OK IsKey(1), Size(60)
D/MtkOmxVenc(  133): EncTime=2
D/MtkOmxVenc(  133): 447ca008 EBD (0x426C4010) (0x4449D000), mNumPendingInput(1)
D/MtkOmxVenc(  133): 447ca008 FBD (0x448A4898) (0x47025000) 147333 (60), mNumPendingOutput(7)
D/CameraSource(  133): signalBufferReturned: 0x4449d000,mFramesBeingEncoded.size()=2
D/MtkOmxVenc(  133): AVC Encode 187465, 115200, 0x00000010, input VA=0x444BA000 :Offset 0x00000000, output VA=0x47125000 :Offset 0x00000000
D/Camera  ( 6254): RRF
E/VDO_LOG (  133): Before set RC address: 0 0
D/CameraClient(  133): RRF:VA(0x4449D000)
D/CameraClient(  133): RRF:VA(0x4449D000), get mLock (6254)
D/MtkCam/CamClient/RecordClient(  133): (6434)[releaseRecordingFrame] Idx(0),VA(0x4449D000)
D/CameraSource(  133): read, mFramesReceived.size= 0,mFramesBeingEncoded.size()= 1
```

Comment: Keep track of the logcat while running native video recorder, maybe you will notice some important difference.

Comment: I have also encountered same problem..with Phone Gionee ELIFE S 5.5 ???? Do anyone resolve this ?